# Why am I unable to use FOR XML EXPLICIT to create CDATA when as a Type?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I currently have a SQL statement similar to the following (I've removed some of the complexity):

```sql
SELECT 
Name as '@name'
,(
    SELECT foo.Name as '@name', foo.Key as '@key'
    FROM foo
    FOR XML Path('foo'), root ('foos'), type
)
,(
    SELECT 
        1 as Tag
        ,null as Parent
        ,bar.Name as 'bar!1!name'
        ,bar.Key as 'bar!1!key'
        ,bar.Content as 'bar!1!!cdata'
    FROM   bar
    FOR XML EXPLICIT, root ('bars'), type
)
FROM baz
FOR XML Path('baz'), root ('bazzes')
```

The outcome of this query is a nice XML value like the following:

```xml
<bazzes>
    <baz name="">
        <foos>
            <foo name="" key=""> 
            </foo>
        </foos>
        <bars>
            <bar name="" key="">
             <content>the content</content>
            </bar>
        </bars>
    </baz>
</bazzes>
```

Notice that the `content` element doesn't have the CDATA markup as expected, I know this i because I have specified it as a `type`.

When I remove the type however, the WHOLE content element get's encoded becoming:

```xml
<bazzes>
    <baz name="">
        <foos>
            <foo name="" key=""> 
            </foo>
        </foos>
        <bars>
            <bar name="" key="">
             &lt;content&gt; etc.
            </bar>
        </bars>
    </baz>
</bazzes>
```

How can I keep the outcome of the query a valid xml value AND remove the type argument so that I get the CDATA markup correctly becoming:

```xml
<bazzes>
        <baz name="">
            <foos>
                <foo name="" key=""> 
                </foo>
            </foos>
            <bars>
                <bar name="" key="">
                 <content><![CDATA[the content]]></content>
                </bar>
            </bars>
        </baz>
    </bazzes>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered.
[XML CDATA Tag is lost when converting to XML data type](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/298860/xml-cdata-tag-is-lost-when-converting-to-xml-data-type)

Using a sub-query in a `for xml path` query will change the result of that sub-query to the XML data type regardless if you use the `type` directive or not.

I can see two workarounds for you. Change the entire query to use `for xml explicit` or do some post-processing string manipulation of the XML that replaces the values of the `content` nodes with the CDATA representation of the value.

Comment: thanks for that, I found out that sqlserver encodes the data and removes the cdata markup, which actually works out okay as well for my needs, so crisis averted!